# Mysql field name within regular expression

Tags: sql, mysql, regex

I have the following table

```
Table bots{
    ip_address varchar(15),
    bot_name varchar(32)
}
```

Given that some bots have static ips and others won't, the table has entries such as 192.168.0 and 192.168.1.15

Now I have to see if a given ip belongs to a bot. I was thinking something along these lines

```
SELECT bot_name
FROM bots
WHERE __input_ip__  REGEXP '^ip_address'
```

but this won't work for the obvious reason that it is looking for a string that starts with ip_address.

So my question is, how can I include a field name within a sql regular expression ?

Comment: So 192.168.1.15 as well as 192.168.1.150, 192.168.1.151, …, 192.168.1.159 would be blocked as they all begin with 192.168.1.15?

Comment: @gumbo, good point. I didn't think about that. If the ip was 192.168.1.15 I would want it to ignore *.150 , *.151 , *152 ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to consider storing the IP address as an INT UNSIGNED.  Also store the netmask so you can tell the difference between a static address and a subnet.

```
INSERT INTO bots (ipaddress, netmask, bot_name) 
VALUES (INET_ATOI('192.168.1.0'), INET_ATOI('255.255.255.0'), 'Wall-E');
```

Then you can query to see if an input IP address matches:

```
SELECT bot_name
FROM bots
WHERE __input_ip__ & netmask = ipaddress & netmask;
```

Using integers for IP addresses instead of CHAR(15) is a common optimization.  Even storing the 8 bytes for the IP address and the netmask is little more than half the storage of the CHAR(15).  And the bitwise operations are likely to be a lot faster than the regular expression matching, and it's easier to avoid the corner cases like in @Gumbo's comment.

Comment: I like this approach, but I think I must be missing something

INSERT into bots(ip_address, network_mask, name)
VALUES (INET_ATON('192.168.0.0'), INET_ATON('255.255.255.0'), 'Wall-E'),
       (INET_ATON('192.168.1.15'), INET_ATON('255.255.255.0'), 'Bender');

#Returns wall-e
SELECT name
FROM bots
WHERE ip_address = INET_ATON('192.168.0.15') & network_mask;

# Returns an empty set
SELECT name
FROM bots
WHERE ip_address = INET_ATON('192.168.1.15') & network_mask;

Comment: Okay, sorry about the mixup, I though you'd always use '0' for the variable part of a dynamic IP address (though I don't know why I'd think this).  I've edited the answer above to apply the netmask to both the ip_address and the input.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT bot_name
FROM bots
WHERE __input_ip__  REGEXP concat('^', replace(ip_address, '.', '\.'))
```

Comment: Won't the `.` characters in the ip_address be interpreted by the regex as 'any character'?  They should be escaped with backslashes, probably with `replace()`

Answer (score 1):

(This is a response to Andrew's answer but doesn't fit in a comment.)

```
WHERE __input_ip__  REGEXP concat('^', replace(ip_address, '.', '\.'))
```

Good plan, except that in MySQL \ is a (non-standard SQL) string literal escape, so to get one in the regexp you'd probably need `'\\\.'`!

...except in ANSI mode it wouldn't. Argh! To be compatible you'd have to get the backslash another way:

```
WHERE __input_ip__ REGEXP CONCAT('^', REPLACE(ip_address, '.', CHAR(92, 46)))
```

Ugh. Maybe better to forget regex and do it with string ops:

```
WHERE LEFT(__input_ip__, CHAR_LENGTH(ip_address))=__input_ip__
```